# Bitwise Operator "|" - Javascript

Tags: javascript

En javascript hay una linea que no me queda claro, el operador bitwise "|", que es lo que hace este operador ?

```
while(num){
 num = (num / 10) | 0;
}
```

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El operador `|` equivale a un `OR` lógico (donde si alguno de los operandos es 1, el resultado es 1), pero al ser del tipo `bitwise`, opera bit-a-bit los bits de los operandos.

El [ejemplo que da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_OR) es bastante claro:

```javascript
const a = 5; // en binario: 0101
//                          vvvv
const b = 3; // en binario: 0011
//                          ----
console.log(a | b); //      0111 = 7 en decimal
```

En el código que adjuntas, al estar siendo operado con `0` el número resultante, está haciendo el equivalente a `parseInt(num/10)`, o sea, quedarse con la parte entera de la división.

Comment: Gracias @carlosabcs, esta linea num = (num / 10) | 0; seria lo mismo que poner un Math.floor(num/10)?

Comment: Correcto! Lo único que está haciendo es quedarse con la parte entera de la división.